# Pygame window freezing when code is run

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to get this code to loop when the right mouse button is pressed, as far as I can see there's nothing wrong with the code, but the pygame window freezes when I click the right button.
Here's my code i'm trying to run:

```
elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 3:
    pressing = 1
    while pressing:
        x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        x1, y1 = x - space_ship_rect.x, y - space_ship_rect.y
        angle = math.atan2(y1, x1)
        movex = speed*math.cos(angle)
        movey = speed*math.sin(angle)
        space_ship_rect.centerx += movex
        space_ship_rect.centery += movey
        print("Right Button Pressed")
    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        pressing = 0
```

Comment: There are different ways to interpret this code depending on the indentation, please fix it. Also, the posting contains sections that are irrelevant to the question, please remove them.

Comment: @möter: the pasted code used tabs; I replaced them with spaces.

Comment: Seems like your `while pressing:` loop is blocking the event thread.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite familiar with Pygame, so the following is based entirely off of my knowledge of other event handlers.

The way event handlers usually work is, their function gets executed **once** per new event. During this handle, they don't respond to new events. Since a MOUSEBUTTONUP would be a new event, you'd need to handle that separately.

The event handler can't do that the way you've currently set up your code since it's stuck handling the MOUSEBUTTONDOWN, freezing the window.

Now here, I'd assume that either the MOUSEBUTTONDOWN gets thrown (with a certain interval inbetween) whilst the button is being pressed, or there is another event that does that. If so, you could simply execute your code once per event, leaving out the loop.

Otherwise, you could launch a new thread that loops your code while some variable is true. You could then set this variable to false in your MOUSEBUTTONUP handler.

Define this outside of your event handler:

```
import thread

mouse_pressing = True

def mouse_pressing_func():
    while mouse_pressing:
        # Do fancy stuff
```

Then use this in your event handler:

```
elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 3:
    mouse_pressing = True
    thread.start_new_thread(mouse_pressing_func, ())
elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 3:
    mouse_pressing = False
```

**Edit:**

Now that the indentation's fixed, I see that you've also got another problem: You don't even check if the event is a MOUSEBUTTONUP in your loop, but afterwards. This means you'll never even reach that statement.

Comment: I'm not exactly understanding what you're trying to tell me, where are you saying I should put the loop?

Comment: @user2993584: jazzpi is saying you shouldn't have a loop at all.

Comment: @user2993584: "execute your code once per event, leaving out the loop."

Comment: @jazzpi That was the whole reason I tried making the loop, the image needs to constantly move when the right button on the mouse is held down. The mousebuttondown only executes once if I hold the button down without a loop :O

Comment: @jazzpi It's probably just me being an idiot as always, but I really don't know what your answer is telling me to do.. :/

Comment: @user2993584: Use [threads](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html). See my edit for a basic example of how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just a flaw in the pasted code, but to me it looks like the `if`-statement at the end of your code istn't in your `while`-loop, so you get an endless loop, which causes your window to freeze. 
Greets, TheWormKill